# Make your site compatible with IE - Where to start?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

So I'm nearly finished with the website I had to make for my school's prom. Now, I just checked it in Internet Explorer and, well, it's hopeless. Elements aren't where they're supposed to be, most of the JavaScript/jQuery doesn't work at all. I am clueless where to start to make my site compatible with **Internet Explorer**. Whats the best way to make your site compatible with **IE**?

Comment: Let's have a look at the code!

Comment: IE is often more finicky because of quirks mode. Making sure your page validates in the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org) should greatly help.

Comment: You're talking about the whole JS and CSS because it's quite a lot...

Comment: I don't know what exactly is happening because I can't see what it looks like in IE, but you may want to look at using a CSS reset if your not already, it may fix some positioning discrepancies across browser platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main cross browser step is [DOCTYPE Declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp).  It is an instruction to the web browser about what version of HTML the page is written in.

Comment: Wow, this alone helped A LOT. I had no idea defining doctype was so important! I still have a few bugs I think, but this is a huge improvement! Thank you very much (:

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be murder to fix what's already broken... you really needed to start off on the right foot, as it is you may need to re-write large chunks of your site in order to get things working again.

Going back?  Well the easiest thing is going to be to start a fresh layout (using the following pointers) and then move your site into the new framework.  Depending on the scale of your site this is no small task.  Your alternative is one-by-one code debugging, with maybe [firebug light](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Going forward, how do you build a site that works more evenly across the board?

**1 Use a `reset` CSS boilerplate**

I like the html5 one at http://html5reset.org/.  These apply layers of CSS to get each browser looking the same to start with (your CSS then gives it the style you want).  Note they DON'T address the variety of ways browsers calculate things - borders being part of the width or not (firefox/ie difference)

**2 Use a JS library**

Or write your own, but be aware of all the differences between the browsers don't just code for the one you're using.  Build some JS tests for the library that you can run in any browser to make sure that the *library* performs as expected, then deal with any site oddities after that.  There's too many JS libraries to make a recommend but [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) are a popular two.

Answer (score 0):

well it's known that there are differences between browsers. The way browsers render CSS code is also different. You should check parts and see how or if it works as you want. :) There is no one-to-all solution. The experience will let you know what works and what not. But to start you could isolate what is not working in IE (javascript code) and then see what alternatives you have. As for the appearance, there is the option of having separate CSS files especially for IE. However, often there is a technique(a different way to implement the same appearance) that lets you create the appearance you want without multiple versions of code.